# Large File uploading Error in AjaxFileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to develop an upload functionality for my website. I am using Ajax Fileupload control for the upload. I have a server event attached for the on uploadcomplete event of the Ajax Fileupload control.

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" Width="350px" onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />
```

Following is code of `onuploadcomplete`

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string fileNameWithPath = Server.MapPath("./files/") + e.FileName.ToString();
            AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(fileNameWithPath);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

I also  Add `maxRequestLength` in `httpRuntime` like This:

```
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="42949672"/>
```

AND

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="42949672"/>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

It Work Properly on Local Host ,but Not work on live site......
at live site it says Uploading Error

Comment: Did you try to increase requests limit to a max value? Something like <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>. Also here it is important to know exact status code, such as 404.13 (content too large) or similar. You can get this via fiddler or network tab of dev tools

Comment: thanks for replay...........http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx    i use this artical of ajax library.....it says you can upload files above 1gb......i install toolkit and setup all code of web.config but not work properly....... @BorysGeneralov

Comment: Are you sure you have given write access for the folder on server where you are saving the file?

Comment: yes i give folder write access but not work...........@KrishanuDey